# Geting multiple performance monitoring interrupt on qemu - kvm

Tags: assembly, intel, qemu, kvm, interrupt-handling

I followed steps and indications given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073038/qemu-kvm-how-to-get-permformance-monitoring-interrupt) and can get now counter overflow interrupt one time. But I cannot get it multple times. Whatever I managed, the Iterrupt does note fires up any more. Despite I take care of clearing the interrupt mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is discussed in this [forum](https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=32869) where they discovered that it is a bug in the kernel. However, your can circumvent it doing this:
At any place where you need to reprogram the msr MSR_PERF_FIXED_CTR0 (0x38d), place these lines:

```
Msr::write(Msr::MSR_PERF_FIXED_CTR0, 0xfffffffffff0ull);
Msr::write(Msr::MSR_PERF_FIXED_CTRL, 0x0);
Msr::write(Msr::MSR_PERF_FIXED_CTR0, 0xfffffffffff0ull);
Msr::write(Msr::MSR_PERF_FIXED_CTRL, 0xa);
```

The switching between the values 0x0 and 0xa causes the kernel to reprogram the counter.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without any code but if you already received the first PMI then the counters registers are set correctly and the problem probably lies in the upper layers<sup>1</sup>.

I would check:

1. **To have sent the [EOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_interrupt) to the LAPIC.**
       
   I assume you configured the PMI register of the local APIC with a fixed vector.
   In this case, you have to send an EOI to the EOI register.
   Quoting Intel (Chapter 10.8.5, Volume 3)

   > For all interrupts except those delivered with the NMI, SMI, INIT, ExtINT, the start-up, or INIT-Deassert delivery
   >   mode, the interrupt handler must include a write to the end-of-interrupt (EOI) register.

   Sample code:

   ```
   mov DWORD [APIC_BASE+0xb0], eax
   ```

   The effective address, for an un-relocated LAPIC, is `0xfee000b0`.
   The written value is not relevant, I picked up a register to keep the encoding of the instruction short.
   Of course, you have to access the LAPIC properly for your context.
2. **To have the `IF` flag set**
    
   To have the `IF` flag clear is an unlikely hypothesis but it is also quite easy to rule out.
   Since an interrupt gate (but not a trap gate) clears the `IF` be sure the way you chose to exit the ISR restores `IF` properly.

---

<sup>1</sup> If I remember correctly, the PMIs don't need to be rearmed.